# Specific Ad Hoc Usage

Tags: meaning, word-choice, meaning-in-context, word-usage

`Ad hoc` is defined as:

> formed, arranged, or done for a particular purpose only.

I have created a computer system to allow distributed machines to connect and run simulations as they become available.  Would it be valid to say the machines run ad hoc simulations?  My gut tells me this is correct, since the simulations are completed in the moment as necessary, but it may be incorrect, since the "particular purpose only" is scheduled.  I may also be completely incorrect.  Is this a valid situation to use ad hoc and why or why not?

Comment: It seems like the simulations are not being formed in the moment, but rather the infrastructure running them is?

Comment: The infrastructure uses an organized process to create simulation requests.  The workers wait for the simulation requests to appear and run them in the moment.  Does that help at all?

Comment: Let me describe what an "ad hoc simulation" sounds like to my computer-knowledgeable, but not simulation-knowledgeable ear. Tell me if it meshes with yours: An ad hoc simulation is constructed on the spur of the moment to test a small question or hypothesis, possibly without rigorous testing.

Comment: Alright, that doesn't seem to match my usage in the question, so I will avoid it for now.  Thank you!  Let's see if any other readers provide an opinion.

Comment: I would suggest that the simulations aren't ad hoc, but the assignment of simulations to machines is.